# php page hosted through MAMP using old website code

Tags: php, html, caching, mamp

So I'm having a problem where my php page, hosted locally through MAMP, is not updating properly. Whether I change the html, php code, the page source/webpage itself still manages to be the same as before. What could the problem be, and how can I fix this?

I've already tried stopping the server and starting it again, and I also double checked file locations & file names.

Comment: Have you cleared your browser's cache?

Comment: yeah, on chrome you just hit the refresh button, correct?

Comment: No, that doesn't clear the cache. You need to go to the "Clear browsing data.." menu item. On Mac it's under the Chrome menu.

Comment: Ok thanks, after that this should work? I thought it's only for javascript you must clear the cache, not for php/html

Comment: Didn't say that was definitely it. But you should always try clearing the browser cache when things get weird.